# How can I correct the icon position in b00merang's windows 10 theme for cinnamon on debian?

Tags: debian, themes, cinnamon

After a fresh installation of debian 8, running cinnamon desktop, I installed b00merang's Windows 10 theme, however the 'gear' icon remains in place and is overlapping my start-button.

What I have tried, is removing the applet, but that just results in the other applets being shifted over causing the same problem, but with different icons. After removing the last applet, the start button disappears and I am forced to reset the UI using `gsettings reset-recursively org.cinnamon` ( `cinnamon --replace` doesn't bring any applets back apparently)

Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing :

[image]

I have also tried unchecking "use custom icon" in the properties of the applet with no change (see screenshot of applet properties page below)

[image]

How can I correct this visual issue without removing any applets ?

Comment: If you select "Use a custom icon", and manually remove the path, it removes the icon, on my cinnamon. However, I did not test with your theme, and I noticed it shrunk the applet a lil bit so it might not work

Comment: Post that as a solution.  It worked perfectly!!!  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already did, you need to access the applet properties, by right-clicking it, selecting "Configure".

The following screen appears:

[image]

Check "Use a custom icon" and remove the path from the input:

[image]

Results in the following menu, shrink but without the icon:

[image]

> Note: Even if checking the checkbox again brings the icon back, the path stays empty. The original value was:
>
> ```
> /usr/share/cinnamon/theme/menu-symbolic.svg
> ```

Comment: Correct. This solution works although my dialog presented the information differently than above.  That is a much prettier dialog than I have -- what are you using to get that more modern layout ?

Comment: Why the layout in itself differs (title of the window, Panel/Menu tabs) I don't know. It might be cinnamon's version, which must be much more up to date on Arch Linux that on Debian (I have 3.2.8, you can see it in System Settings > System Info)